# "Back engineering" an R package from compiled binary version

Tags: r, r-package

I work for an organization with a number of internal R packages, all written many years ago. These are stored as `.zip` archives built on Windows under R 3.x. They cannot be loaded on Linux or macOS or under R 4.y without being rebuilt. Unfortunately, I do not have access to the package sources. They are lost to time...

I want to take these binaries, extract the source code, and repackage it according to current best practices (version control, **roxygen2**, **testthat**, etc.). What is the best way to do that?

I have already tackled one of the binaries by:

1. Manually copying the source code of objects (exported and internal functions, data sets, etc.) in the loaded namespace to new `.R` files.
2. Manually adding Roxygen blocks to the `.R` files in order to reproduce the help pages as displayed in the browser.

I am partly stuck at (1) because some of the functions are S4 generic. `dput(<name>)` gives `new("standardGeneric", ...)` as opposed to a simple `function` definition. Otherwise, the process has been fairly straightforward, but *very* time consuming.

Is there a way to *programmatically* "back engineer" source files from R package binaries, while handling S4 generic functions, classes, and methods correctly?

Everyone in the organization will be stuck on R 3.6 until this problem is resolved.

Comment: I doubt I have sufficient expertise for this, but shouldn't it be possible to iterate over the namespace without copying things by hand?

Comment: In the R-internal manual (https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-ints.pdf), pages 21-22 something is discussed regarding how the R source file is converted in the compiled package. I guess that if the package you are trying to rebuild has some compiled C/C++ code, there won't be much that you can do.

Comment: There's not a one-size-fits-all way to do this. Without any sort of [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) it's really impossible to offer specific suggestions. Every package is different and without knowing exactly what the requirements are or how to measure "success", this really can't be answered.

Comment: What might `dput()` do for these custom objects and for their methods?  This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3474049) should handle the complexities of reproducing nested objects, if `dput()` falls short.

Comment: @hokeybot  Just bountied this question.  I've wrestled with some reverse-engineering myself, and I'm curious as to the answer (if any) for the `standardGeneric`s and custom objects.  **I suggest you post a snippet of SOURCE CODE for one of those items, so any "bounty hunters" have a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to work with**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out if this works in `R 3.6`.

Below script can automate least part of your problem by writing all function sources into separate and appropriately named `.R` files. This code will also take care of hidden functions.

#### Extracting code

```
# Use your package name
package_name <- "dplyr" 

# Extract all method names, including hidden
nms <- paste(lsf.str(paste0("package:", package_name), all.names = TRUE))

# Loop through the method names,
# extract head and body, and write them to R files
for (i in 1:length(nms)) {

    # Extract name
    nm <- nms[i]

    # Extract head
    hd_raw <- capture.output(args(nms[i]))
    # Collapse raw output, but drop trailing NULL
    hd <- paste0(hd_raw[-length(hd_raw)], collapse = "\n")

    # Extract body, collapse
    bd <- paste0(capture.output(body(nms[i])), collapse = "\n")
    
    # Write all to file
    write(paste0(hd, bd), file = paste0(nm, ".R"))
}
```

#### Extracting help files

To extract a functions's help text a similar way, you can use code from the following SO answers:

- for plain text: [Get the documentation of an R function from the help as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53559185/9406040)
- for `.Rd` file contents: [How to access the help/documentation .rd source files in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7496363/9406040)

A starting point could be something like:

```
library(tools)
package_name <- "dplyr" 
db <- Rd_db(package_name)

# Extract all method names, including hidden
nms <- paste(lsf.str(paste0("package:", package_name), all.names = TRUE))

# Loop through the method names,
# extract Rd contents if they exist in this namespace, 
# and write them to new Rd files
for (i in 1:length(nms)) {
    
    # Extract name
    nm <- nms[i]
    
    rd_raw <- db[names(db) %in% paste0(nm, ".Rd")]
    if (length(rd_raw) > 0) {
        rd <- paste0(capture.output(rd_raw), collapse = "\n")
        # Write all to file
        write(rd, file = paste0(nm, ".Rd"))
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You can capture a function with a single line: `fn |> base::dput() |> utils::capture.output() |> base::paste0(collapse = "\n")`

Comment: Good point! Didn't think of using `dput` here.

Comment: Thank you, this is incredibly helpful!   
  
I only had to edit the help extraction code slightly (`".rd"` not `".Rd"`).  
  
Now i just need to figure out how to recreate the S4 custom generic...

Comment: @hokeybot To build off [@Roman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9406040/roman)'s suggestion for help files, you might leverage the [**`Rd2roxygen`**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rd2roxygen/vignettes/Rd2roxygen.html) package, to convert those `.rd` files back into [roxygen](https://roxygen2.r-lib.org/) comments.