# Extract function argument description from R package

Tags: r, package, documentation

I know there are ways to extract all arguments to a function using, for example, `rlang::fn_fmls`. But is it possible to extract the description of one of these arguments from the package documentation?

For example, what if I wanted to extract the description of the `na.rm` argument to `base::sum()`?

I'm imagining something like:

`get_argument_description(fn = 'base::sum', arg = 'na.rm')`

Return:

`"logical. Should missing values (including NaN) be removed?"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to read the associated help file for that function, and `grep` the line where `\item{argument}`. However, multi-line help texts are allowed, if the next line does not start with a `\` you would want to grab that too.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7496363/3212698) shows a way to acess the file, then it is just a matter of grabbing the correct line(s). I also want to highlight a different function in `tools`,

```
tools:::.Rd_get_text()
```

Which almost gets you where you want, (if you find the correct line)

```
library(tools)
db = Rd_db("base")
tools:::.Rd_get_text(x = db[["sum.Rd"]])[21] # 21 is the line you want here

[1] "   na.rm: logical.  Should missing values (including 'NaN') be removed?"
```

Comment: This does indeed get me closer. Thank you!